# Camera from POCO M3 returns unreadable image bytes

Tags: image

I'm trying to detect faces fith ml_kit_face_detection on flutter.
It works fine for other phones. But on POCO M3 ml kit can't detect faces.

I take one of image from camera & save it to file.
The file is bellow:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvt2klSwWFA5YL96bz1itfeEX4dai4Oh/view?usp=sharing

I undersand that the file is not readable. I tryed to convert it to base64 but it also no readable.

I'm trying to convert it to png & got this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse engineering the format is challenging...

The file format is raw binary format, with some non-standard padding.

I managed to get the following result:
[image]
It looks right, but I am not sure that it is entirely correct....

It looks like the file format is [NV12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/4-2-0-video-pixel-formats) (or NV21) with some padding.
For better understanding NV12 format, you may refer to my [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022633/how-to-convert-srgb-to-nv12-format-using-numpy).

---

By reverse engineering the file I figured out the following information:

Image resolution: 1280x720
The stored resolution is 1536x720 (there is a padding of 256 pixels in the right side).

File storage format (raw binary format):

- Y channel plane: First 1536x719+720 bytes.
- UV channel plane: 1536x360 bytes.
- Spare bytes, and duplication for UV channel plane.
  I don't know why UV channel is duplicated, but the data looks identical.

Illustration:

```
                     256 padding bytes
                   <----->
        1536 bytes
<------------------------>
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY00000000
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY00000000
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY00000000   719 rows
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY00000000
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY00000000
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY   <--- 1280 bytes (last row of Y)
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV00000000
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV00000000  359 rows
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV00000000
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV   <---- 1280 bytes (last row of UV)
```

---

MATLAB code that reads the data and convert to RGB:

```matlab
f = fopen('photo', 'r');  % Open binary file for reading.
I1 = fread(f, [1536, 719], '*uint8')'; % Read 1536x719 image (Y channel).
I1last_row = fread(f, 1280, '*uint8')'; % Read 1280 bytes (last row of Y).
I2 = fread(f, [1536, (720-1)/2], '*uint8')'; % Read 1536x359 image (UV channel).
I2last_row = fread(f, 1280, '*uint8')'; % Read 1280 bytes (last row of UV). 
fclose(f);
%figure;imshow(I1);impixelinfo % Show I1 for testing.
%figure;imshow(I2);impixelinfo % Show I2 for testing.

I1 = I1(:, 1:1280); % Crop valid part: 1280x719 pixels.
I1 = [I1; I1last_row]; % Add last row to the bottom (complete to 1280x720).

I2 = I2(:, 1:1280); % Crop valid part (1280x359 UV elements).
I2 = [I2; I2last_row]; % Add last row to the bottom. (complete to 1280x360).

% Convert from NV12 to RGB:
Y = I1;
U = I2(:, 1:2:end); % Extract U color channel 
V = I2(:, 2:2:end); % Extract V color channel 
U = imresize(U, size(Y)); % Resize U to be the same size of Y
V = imresize(V, size(Y)); % Resize V to be the same size of Y
YUV = cat(3, Y, U, V); % Merge Y,U,V channels
RGB = ycbcr2rgb(YUV); % Convert from YCbCr color format to RGB.

% Show and save RGB for testing:
figure;imshow(RGB);impixelinfo 
imwrite('RGB', RGB);
```

---

Note:

- For better figuring out the format (NV12 or NV21), I suggest you to take a picture with various colors. Post the raw file, and if you can, post a colored reference image for comparison.